# error MissingpluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocementsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello guys this program consists of two pages named student list and studentdetail it don't make any error in the analyzer but in emulator when I open the first page that display list of students and tap on any student and go to the student detail and wanting to delete , update or goback to the fist page it says MissingpluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocementsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider in console and I can't delete or add student and in student page

```
    class Student {
  late int _id ;
  late String _name;
  late String _description;
  late int _pass;
  late String _date;

  Student(this._name, this._description, this._pass, this._date);

  Student.withId(
      this._id, this._name, this._description, this._pass, this._date);

  String get date => _date;

  int get pass => _pass;

  String get description => _description;

  String get name => _name;

  int get id => _id;

  set date(String value) {
    _date = value;
  }

  set pass(int value) {
    if (value >= 1 && value <= 2) {
      _pass = value;
    }
  }

  set description(String value) {
    if (value.length <= 255) {
      _description = value;
    }
  }

  set name(String value) {
    if (value.length <= 255) {
      _name = value;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["id"] = this._id;
    map["name"] = this._name;
    map["description"] = this._description;
    map["pass"] = this._pass;
    map["date"] = this._date;
    return map;
  }

  Student.getMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._id = map["id"];
    this._name = map["name"];
    this._description = map["description"];
    this._pass = map["pass"];
    this._date = map["date"];
  }
}
```

when i write   late int _id ; it says late initialization error after field _id hasn't been initialized after add or delete student
this is the entire code
https://github.com/abdelrahman992-cpu/studentfinal

Comment: The problem lies with your implementation of path_provider. Your model code is totally unrelatable here. Please post your path provider code segment

Answer (score 0):

run these commands in terminals hope this will help you

```
>> flutter clean

>> flutter pub get
```

if this didn't worked try stopping and restarting the app. let me know if this help you or not.

Comment: I using flutlab site to make android projects how to flutter clean

Comment: so if you are using website platform. path_provider doesn't support that you can read it here https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Comment: can I add path_provider in pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: yeah you can add but you can check on the webpage of the package it support only Platform Android, iOS, Linux, macOS, Windows

Comment: okey how to add in platform windows ?

Comment: you can check on the pub.dev there it is mentioned that it support window 10 and the method given there are Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

Comment: where is pub.dev

Comment: https://pub.dev/

Comment: what will i do in pub.dev

Comment: here you will read about the path_provider package.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/install    in any page in my project add import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying

Comment: i have many pages in my project that i write it git hub link in any page in my project wirte this pharse import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Comment: can you explain your problem carefully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251340/discussion-between-munsif-ali-and-abdelrahmandarrage).